# text input value greater 10 not more than 5000 jQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an html set the input text which value must be more than 10 and below 5000. Indeed my code seems not working , Kindly advise .

jQUERY :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".zijin_input").keyup(function() {
            if ((this).value() > 10) {
                $(".zijin_button").css("display", "block");
                $(".zijin_button_span").css("display","none");
                $('.cunkuan_line_2').addClass('cunkuan_line_3').removeClass('cunkuan_line_2');
                // $("#lineBAR").addClass('cunkuan_line_3'); 
            }
            else {
                $(".zijin_button").css("display", "none");
                $(".zijin_button_span").css("display","block");
                $('.cunkuan_line_3').addClass('cunkuan_line_2').removeClass('cunkuan_line_3');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't  `if ((this).value() > 10)` be `if ($(this).value() > 10)` ? Missing `$` from the selector `$(this)`

Comment: Sounds like a `range` or `number` input may work for you. You'd need no validation if you used that. Also note that `val()` (which you should be using) returns a string, so you need to convert it to an integer using `parseInt()` before comparing it to `10`

Comment: change `(this).value()` to `$(this).val()`

Comment: Or to `this.value`, which is equivalent for text inputs.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Hi Frederic , Thanks for the info ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".zijin_input").keyup(function() {
            if ($(this).val() > 10  && $(this).val()<5000) {
                $(".zijin_button").css("display", "block");
                $(".zijin_button_span").css("display","none");
                $('.cunkuan_line_2').addClass('cunkuan_line_3').removeClass('cunkuan_line_2');
                // $("#lineBAR").addClass('cunkuan_line_3'); 
            }
            else {
                $(".zijin_button").css("display", "none");
                $(".zijin_button_span").css("display","block");
                $('.cunkuan_line_3').addClass('cunkuan_line_2').removeClass('cunkuan_line_3');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: `this.value` is more efficient than `$(this).val()`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Hi James , may i know how to change the this.value to implement on it ? thanks you

Comment: @MorganNg simply change `$(this).val()` to `this.value`: `if (this.value > 10 && this.value <= 5000)`.

Comment: @Morgan Ng thank you,. please upvote my answer which its really helped you

Answer (score 0):

Should be like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".zijin_input").keyup(function() {
        if ($(this).val() > 10) {
            $(".zijin_button").css("display", "block");
            $(".zijin_button_span").css("display","none");
            $('.cunkuan_line_2').addClass('cunkuan_line_3').removeClass('cunkuan_line_2');
            // $("#lineBAR").addClass('cunkuan_line_3'); 
        }
        else {
            $(".zijin_button").css("display", "none");
            $(".zijin_button_span").css("display","block");
            $('.cunkuan_line_3').addClass('cunkuan_line_2').removeClass('cunkuan_line_3');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `this.value` is more efficient than `$(this).val()`.

Comment: but we already have an instance of $(this) no need to go on javascript object

Comment: `value` is a property of `this`. `$(this)` is a function which converts `this` into a jQuery object which contains the function `val()`, which converts the jQuery object back to what it originally was (`this`) then reads its `value` property. Thus, `this.value` is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $(".zijin_input").keyup(function() {
        if ( parseInt($(this).val()) > 10  && parseInt($(this).val()) < 5000) {
        $(".zijin_button").css("display", "block");
            $(".zijin_button_span").css("display","none");
            $('.cunkuan_line_2').addClass('cunkuan_line_3').removeClass('cunkuan_line_2');
            // $("#lineBAR").addClass('cunkuan_line_3'); 

        }
        else {
           $(".zijin_button").css("display", "none");
            $(".zijin_button_span").css("display","block");
            $('.cunkuan_line_3').addClass('cunkuan_line_2').removeClass('cunkuan_line_3');
        }
    });
```

check this link   https://jsfiddle.net/5jhk4yzu/

Answer (score 0):

```
("#amount").bind("keyup keydown", function() {
    var amount = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if (amount) {
        if (amount < 500 || amount > 800) {
            $("span.paymentalert").html("Your payment must be between £500 and £800");
        } else {
            $("span.paymentalert").html("");
        }
    } else {
        $("span.paymentalert").html("Your payment must be a number");
    }
});
```